# React Semantic UI Modal closeicon doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

I want to make a modal for my App. I've tried everything, and my closeicon won't close my modal. It works fine when I do modal in the same file, but I want make my modal as separate component. Is something wrong with my code?

Parent Component:

```
import { Card, Placeholder, Image, Icon } from "semantic-ui-react";
import BookModal from "./BookModal";
import { useState } from "react";

const BookCard = props => {

    const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false)


    return (
        <Card onClick={() => setShowModal(true)}>
            <Image><Placeholder><Image src={props.image} size="large" /></Placeholder></Image>
            <Card.Content>
                <Card.Header>{props.title}</Card.Header>
                <Card.Meta>
                    <span className='date'>{props.publishedDate}</span>
                </Card.Meta>
                <Card.Description>{props.author}</Card.Description>
            </Card.Content>
            <Card.Content extra>
                <Icon name='star'>Rating</Icon>    
            </Card.Content>
            <BookModal key="Modal1" open={showModal} onClose={() => setShowModal(false)}/>
        </Card>
     );
}
 
export default BookCard;
```

Children Component Modal:

```
import { Modal } from "semantic-ui-react";

const BookModal = props => {

    return ( 
        <Modal
          closeIcon
          onClose={props.onClose}
          open={props.open} >

            <Modal.Header>
              <h2>Modal content</h2>
            </Modal.Header>

        </Modal>
     );
}

 
export default BookModal;
```

Comment: Looks like a typo - in the **BookModal** component you set the `<Modal>`'s open state by `props.isOpen`, but in the **BookCard** component you pass it a property called `open`, and not `isOpen`

Comment: Corrected, but still nothing, when I console.log showModal when clicking closeIcon, it says true all the time

Answer (score 1):

You have run into an interesting problem -- when you click the X icon to close the modal, the `<Card>` component also receives this click!

So the `onClick` handler in the card code runs when you try to close the modal, and sets the open state to `true` again. This happens *after* the `onClose` handler in the modal is run, so the modal will stay open.

You can change the code to open modal on the `<Image>` click instead:

```
    <Card>
      <Image
        onClick={() => setShowModal(true)}
      >
        <Placeholder>
          <Image src={props.image} size="large" />
        </Placeholder>
      </Image>
      <Card.Content>
        <Card.Header>{props.title}</Card.Header>
        <Card.Meta>
          <span className="date">{props.publishedDate}</span>
        </Card.Meta>
        <Card.Description>{props.author}</Card.Description>
      </Card.Content>
      <Card.Content extra>
        <Icon name="star">Rating</Icon>
      </Card.Content>
      <BookModal
        key="Modal1"
        open={showModal}
        onClose={() => setShowModal(false)}
      />
    </Card>
```

You can see it all working here: https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-example-forked-yy7p3?file=/BookCard.js

Because the `<Image>` component is a sibling and not the parent of the `<BookModal>` component, the click will not "fall through" or "bubble up" (whatever semantics you prefer) into it.

Another way is to keep the modal trigger *inside* the modal. This is how their own examples do it -- you can find a simplified one here: https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-example-forked-qo99z?file=/example.js